# Why the need for closing a file within 'finally' and still have it embedded within a 'try/catch' block?

Tags: java, try-catch

The following code snippet ...

```
    try
    {
        myFile = new FileInputStream( "something.dat" );
        ...
    }
    catch ( IOExcpetion ioe ) 
    { 
        ... 
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            myFile.close();
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) 
        {
            ... 
        }
    }
```

... is closing the file within finally, which I understand. But why is it necessary to have another try/catch block within? It seems awkward to me. Is there a way around this?

Comment: What happens if you remove the final `try`/`catch` block, and just call `myFile.close()`? You'll see why the `try` is necessary.

Comment: Take a look at [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) if you feel your current code is awkward.

Comment: @GregHewgill Thank you for answering. But I don't think I was clear enough. I know syntactically that it is required... but it seems awkward. I wanted to know the reasons for Java having designed it this way. Secondly, I wanted to know if there was a more convenient way to write the above.

Comment: `FileInputStream.close()` throws `IOException` therefore you need a `try-catch` around `myfile.close()`

Comment: @KarthikKalyanasundaram Can you kindly read my comment above. Thanks.

Comment: Better way: use try with resources and you don't have to use a try-catch inside your finally statement

Comment: There are two possible reasons: 1. if your method doesn't throw IOException it will need to be caught. 2. if the close method then does throw an exception the catch will "eat it" rather than it being thrown and the code after the finally block wont be reached.

Comment: @morgano That sounds good. Can you please provide any examples or perhaps a link to a resource that I could check online?

Comment: @grateful, check this answer in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17739460/2164109 for an example of how to transform your code using try with resources

Comment: @Grateful, Karthik's comment is good explanation. You need a `try-catch` cause `FileInputStream.close()` throws `IOException`. Where are you closing your file is completely up to you. It is not anywhere written that you must close it in `finally`. Rather, it is convenient that even if there is some exception coming in your primary `try` block, your file closes successfully.

Comment: *"I wanted to know the reasons for Java having designed it this way.*" - Because you can do anything within the final block and Java has no idea what you might do, and what you might do might cause another exception. A final block is just another block of code, there's nothing special about it (from within the block itself).  *"I wanted to know if there was a more convenient way to write the above"* - try-with-resources in Java 7+

Comment: @morgano Wow. That is so cool. I would like you to provide this as a solution so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Grateful no worries man, for now it is sufficient to know that I was helpful to you; you can take ankur-singhal's answer as the accepted one, and if you found my answer in the other question useful, just upvote it :-)

Comment: @morgano Thanks man. I have selected his answer with your permission.

Comment: remember to never throw a HeatDeathOfTheUniverseException because it wont be caught. it will just sit there for all of eternity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `close()` method on `FIleInputStream`, has to be surrounded by `try catch` clause. The API method itself is throwing the **IOException exception**. Also [IOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) is the checked exception, so we need to handle this.

**Checked Exception**

> Checked exceptions are checked at compile-time. It means if a method
>   is throwing a checked exception then it should handle the exception
>   using try-catch block or it should declare the exception using throws
>   keyword, otherwise the program will give a compilation error. It is
>   named as checked exception because these exceptions are checked at
>   Compile time.

From the API,

```
/**
     * Closes this file input stream and releases any system resources
     * associated with the stream.
     *
     * <p> If this stream has an associated channel then the channel is closed
     * as well.
     *
     * @exception  IOException  if an I/O error occurs.
     *
     * @revised 1.4
     * @spec JSR-51
     */
    public void close() throws IOException {
}
```

Since the `close()`, method is throwing `IOException`, either you need to `re-throw the same` or surround the statement with `try/catch`.

Refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#close%28%29)

Also talking about Java7, conveniently you can handle the same

1.) [Catching Multiple Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html)

2.) [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

To understand the causes of IOException, please refer similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216148/java-what-throws-an-ioexception).

Answer (score 0):

Things you need to know

**finally block**

This block guarantees that the code written in this block will be executed for sure after the execution of try or catch block. It executes whether the exception occurs or not.

**Why to write close() in finally**

Because we want to close our file irrespective of whether exception occurs or not.

**Why close() needs try-catch**

For this you need to know what [CheckedExceptions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Checked_Exceptions) are.

In short I would say, CheckedExceptions are those which are mandatory to handle i.e. you either need to write it with in try-catch block or declare to be thrown by `throws` keyword. If you see the source code of `close()` method you will come to know that it throws `java.io.IOException` which is checked exception, so you need to write this in try-catch.