# Java exception handling (IOException)

Tags: java

/* In this above example when it will display output of Catch i.e. [Error May be Occured in Input]. Please give me the input. */

```
 import java.io.IOException; 
    public class ThrowsClause 
    { 
         static boolean guess() throws IOException //Throws Clause
         { 
             char ch='r'; 
             System.out.print("Guess any Character(a-z) : "); 
             char n=(char)System.in.read(); 
             return(ch==n); 
          } 
         public static void main(String[] args) 
         { 
              boolean result; 
              try 
             { 
                  result=guess(); //Back to method
                  if(result==true) 
                     System.out.println("Your Guess is Perfect"); 
                  else 
                     System.out.println("Your Guess is Incorrect"); 
              } 
                  catch(IOException e) 
              { 
                     System.out.println("Error May be Occured in Input"); //I want input to display this statement as a output`
               } 
          } 
    } 

/* In this above example when it will display output of Catch i.e. [Error May be Occured in Input]. Please give me the input. */
```

Comment: and what is your question ?

Comment: well if you want to throw any exception programatically . You can do 
throw new IOException();
at any point you want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program will only print the `Error May be Occured in Input` message if an `IOException` occurs. [The Javadocs state that this will only happen if an input/output error occurs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) while getting user input.

Comment: What input you will provide. Because I had tried multiple input combination.

Comment: See this question for more information on an `IOException`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216148/java-what-throws-an-ioexception