# Files.delete did not delete the folder correctly

Tags: java

In the springboot project, after the files have been merged, they need to be deleted.
The main code for the merge method is：

```
// chunkFolder indicates the file storage folder path
Files.list(Paths.get(chunkFolder))
                .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().contains(HYPHEN))
                .sorted((p1, p2) -> {
                    String fileName1 = p1.getFileName().toString();
                    String fileName2 = p2.getFileName().toString();
                    int index1 = fileName1.indexOf(HYPHEN);
                    int index2 = fileName2.indexOf(HYPHEN);
                    return Integer.valueOf(fileName1.substring(0, index1)).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(fileName2.substring(0, index2)));
                })
                .forEach(path -> {
                            try {
                                Files.write(Paths.get(target), Files.readAllBytes(path), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                );
```

The delete method is:

```
 public void deleteDirectory(Path targetPath) throws IOException {
        Files.walk(targetPath).sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).forEach(path -> {
            try {
                Files.delete(path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

In the windows environment test, delete the storage path after merging. However, the results show that the folder still exists, but cannot be accessed. If you stop the springboot project, the folder disappears.

Comment: Sounds the same as [Files.delete does not delete empty directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62132957/files-delete-does-not-delete-empty-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happens on Windows when you are not closing all the directory streams correctly. You must close all directory streams  scanned in your code. The two examples you've shown can be fixed with try with resources:

```
try(Stream<Path> stream = Files.list( ... )) {
    ... your code
    stream.xyz(...);
}
```

... plus same for `Files.walk()` in `deleteDirectory`. Check other similar calls in all code.

When this occurs the directory is in a strange state when viewed in Windows Explorer - visible but not accessible. Shutting down the VM clears up correctly and the folder disappears from Explorer.